# JavaScript only half-executing non-last table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a database, with three tables. I have three pages, each displaying certain results from one table. I also have a search form, which searches all three tables and displays the results in...three different tables.

Rather than copy and paste a bunch of code, and have to make three changes whenever I want to change how it looks, the search page simply sets a variable with the name of the first table, includes the search code, changes the table name variable to the second table, includes the search code, changes the table name variable to the third table, and includes the search code.

I've got JQuery set up to allow me to show information from one column in a div outside the HTML table when a certain column's information is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".teamDiv").click(function() {
        var rosterID = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".roster").not("#" + rosterID).fadeOut(500);
        $("#" + rosterID).fadeIn(500);
    })
});
// -->
</script>
```

This works fine in the single-table pages, but in the search form it only works on whichever of the tables was loaded last. So, if there are results from only two tables, only the second works. If there are results from all three tables, only the third works. If I enter a search that takes long enough to load the page, and stop the page loading before the first table is complete that table works, but if I let the page finish loading it stops working and only the last table works.

Which is odd enough, but what happens when I click on a .teamDiv in a table that isn't working isn't nothing. If there's a roster visible, it executes the fadeOut. So it appears to simply be failing to find the correct ID. Which makes no sense, given the code is exactly the same in all three cases, and the failing tables differ depending on what results there are.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same id values in all the tables? Because that right there would be the problem.

Comment: All the divs in the search results have different IDs, if that's what you mean. They're generated through PHP, from the ID and Team Name columns in the MySQL table. The div to be clicked on and the div to be displayed have the same ID, though, but that works fine when only displaying one table, so I'm not sure why others would be a problem.

Comment: Instead of $(".teamDiv"), try $("body").on("click",".teamDiv", function(){});

Comment: Now nothing happens in any table.

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in the code. Having fixed that, that suggestion achieves exactly the same thing as my original code did.